# Is it possible to change windows language on program start?

Tags: windows

I'm using a swedish keyboard and keep Swedish set as my language on the language bar. However, when I'm programming, I prefer setting it to English since most programming languages use brackets and similar symbols which are placed in less optimal positions in Swedish layout.

I'm currently using alt+shift to switch language. It's better than nothing, but it still often makes my windows lose focus. I would prefer if there was a way to have the language bar change the language automatically when I start certain programs such as Visual Studio 2012, cmd.exe etc.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Just to clarify, I'm talking about having windows automatically switch my input language, not changing the language of the OS, nor the programs.